# New elasticsearch-java API `CreateIndexRequest` using `.withJson` causes `co.elastic.clients.util.MissingRequiredPropertyException`

Tags: json, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-java-api

I am having a hard time on using the new elasticsearch-java api client.

I am migrating from HLRC to the new elasticsearch java api.

When I create an index, I used CreateIndexRequest  and load it with json source

But why is it resulting to an exception, seems that there are missing required properties

Are all properties needed to be in the json file?
But why is it when I used Kibana, the json file works even I just put the needed properties?

Also in the deprecated HLRC client, the json works when using its CreateIndexRequest.

Also this is in a springboot environment

I used the following

- org.elasticsearch: elasticsearch 7.17.4
- co.elastic.clients: elasticsearch-java  7.17.4
- jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api 2.0.1
- com.fasterxml.kackson: jackson-databind 2.13.3

Below is the exception

```
     co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing 
    co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.analysis.TokenizerDefinition: 
    co.elastic.clients.util.MissingRequiredPropertyException: Missing required property 
    'PathHierarchyTokenizer.bufferSize' (JSON path: 
    settings.analysis.tokenizer.unix_path_tokenizer) (line no=15, column no=10, offset=377)
```

Below is my code

```
    final String assetJsonSource = "./config/elasticsearch/my_index_settings.json";
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(assetJsonSource)) {
      CreateIndexRequest request =
          CreateIndexRequest.of(builder -> builder.index(indexName).withJson(input));
      CreateIndexResponse response = client2.indices().create(request);
      boolean ack = Boolean.TRUE.equals(response.acknowledged());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Failed to create an index", e);
    }
```

The json I used is :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "max_ngram_diff": 2,
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "3",
          "token_chars": ["letter", "digit", "punctuation", "symbol"]
        },
        "unix_path_tokenizer": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy"
        },
        "whitespace_tokenizer": {
          "type": "whitespace"
        },
        "keyword_tokenizer": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
          "char_filter": ["icu_normalizer"],
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        },
        "lowercase_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        },
        "directory_path_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "unix_path_tokenizer"
        },
        "whitespace_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace_tokenizer"
        },
        "keyword_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "lowercase": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
          }
        }
      },
      "path": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "directory_path_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "full": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "originalSize": {
        "type": "double",
        "store": "true"
      },
      "assetCategory": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "mimetype": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "importedBy": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "true"
      },
      "updatedBy": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "importedAt": {
        "type": "date",
        "store": "true"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "date",
        "store": "true"
      },
      "fileCreatedAt": {
        "type": "date",
        "store": "true"
      },
      "fileUpdatedAt": {
        "type": "date",
        "store": "true"
      },
      "metadataSet": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "instanceId": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "referenceId": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "cutComment": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "lowercase": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
          }
        }
      },
      "comment": {
        "properties": {
          "userId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
            "fields": {
              "lowercase": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
              }
            }
          },
          "updatedAt": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
      },
      "shadow": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "store": "true"
      },
      "shadowUpdatedAt": {
        "type": "date",
        "store": "true"
      },
      "downloadValue": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "collection": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "sha1": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "subtitle": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
      },
      "videoOcr": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
      },
      "version": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "cmeta_str": {
          "match": "cmeta_str-*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "store": "true",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
            "fields": {
              "lowercase": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "cmeta_select": {
          "match": "cmeta_select-*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "store": "true",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
            "fields": {
              "lowercase": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "cmeta_bool": {
          "match": "cmeta_bool-*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "store": "true"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "cmeta_double": {
          "match": "cmeta_double-*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "double",
            "store": "true"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "cmeta_date": {
          "match": "cmeta_date-*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "date",
            "store": "true"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "cmeta_multi_label": {
          "match": "cmeta_multi_label-*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "long",
            "store": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the new client requires explicit values for the path hierarchy tokenizer even if they are default.
(see [default values here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) )

You need to add default values to:

```
"unix_path_tokenizer": {
   "type": "path_hierarchy"
}
```

becomes:

```
"unix_path_tokenizer": {
   "type": "path_hierarchy"
   "delimiter": "/",
   "buffer_size": "1024",
   "replacement": "/",
   "reverse": "false",
   "skip": "0"
}
```

If you miss any default value, the error will change to that missing property.

Comment: not only this one. "type" which is optional, is as well in the API mandatory :(